# When someone gives you a PSD and tells you to convert it into a web page

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

I was given a code challenge to do this.  I've read and watched some tutorials about how to do it, and have run into a lot of stuff about how this "workflow" of PSD to HTML is dead.

In my opinion, it's not that hard to bring a design to fruition with HTML and CSS but there's definitely still some questions that linger when given this assignment without very specific instructions and lacking much practical experience in this realm.  Here are some...

1. Given that most websites are responsive and I assume that's the expectation for new sites, should you take the pixel width and height of PSD layers literally and give them a fixed width/height? Or should you use some other approach such as measuring the relative width/height (like as a percentage) of a specific section?
2. When is it appropriate or recommended to crop a portion of a PSD and include it as an image rather than drawing it yourself with HTML/CSS?

Comment: ...it is like traveling back in time to the late 1990s...

Comment: this question being relevant, or converting a psd to html?  I am new to web development. Trying to inherit some history

Comment: Converting a PSD to HTML was still relevant in the late 2000s.

Comment: @natecraft1 just the psd to html part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) make sure the site looks like it's supposed to look in the psd. with tools like bootstrap at your disposal it's easy to make it responsive. Fixed widths are never OK unless you're using media queries to change them based on the window size. But don't reinvent the wheel, again - tools like bootstrap exist. take advantage of someone else's hard work.

2.) Never. Never ever. The most important part of building a site is that it is accessible to all people it's important that each element has what it's supposed to ie alt and title tags for those with disabilities. Equally important, if not more, is that the page loads as quickly as is possible. CSS styles and optimized images(ie using a 1px bg image and repeating it, making sure it's the right type of image for the situation, etc.) load way fast than just cramming images in a div to make it look right, plus an image cannot be responsive the way markup can be.

Obviously these are mostly opinion based, so this answer might get shut down. But the real answer is make something that works great regardless of resolution, is made for all users, and don't be lazy and take short cuts.

Comment: Cool Bryan thanks for this, learned a lot.  I was curious about the 1px background image repeat because I've never heard of that.  I researched it a bit and ran into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410994/images-in-browsers-performance-for-background-repeat-css.  Does that mean it's better to have images the size of whatever div it's going in rather than little bits?  Or is this a different type of scenario.

Comment: if you're using a background image that's say a gradient, it makes sense to just repeat it. Since we're talking about responsive designs you don't know what size the div might be. talking 1px vs 10px is trivial.(ie the link) but talking 1kb vs 300kb is a huge change in user experience, especially if it's not just once. Do it when it makes sense, it's really a judgement call.

Answer (score 1):

1) My advice is to go responsive. Substitute every static element you see in Photoshop with a percentage. How do you know the percentuage of a static element? You need to calculate it. I give you an example, if your Photoshop website has a max-width of 1000px, and you have a column of 320px, you've got to divide 1000/320 = 32%.

Also, always start with a "Mobile First" attitude, meaning that you should build the website from small to large, so that more complex styles are only visible on larger screens sizes, in this way you don't confuse mobile users. Learn to use `EM` and `REM` units instead of pixels (be aware that `REM` are not supported in IE8), this will give you the ability to scale your website easily if in the future you want to change it.

**Super important:** apply `box-sizing: border-box` to all the elements in the page, this will make your life easy because if you apply padding or margin to an element, it will not get bigger than the percentuage you've specified.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

2) It is simple. Crop and use an image only when you are 100% sure that it can't be created with CSS (for example if you need to add the logo or other bitmap-related graphics).

Comment: meh, only using percentages isn't really responsive, it just makes it scale. and relying on CSS that doesn't work in ie 8 is a bad idea, there are still a lot of people on older browsers. I only use css that's not supported in all browsers to make something look better. If the browser doesn't support it, they don't get that extra effect, but it doesn't break the page.(talking about box sizing here) Rather just calculate for border and padding and know for sure it will work in all browsers.

Comment: I agree, you also need to use Media Queries, I just can't enumerate all techniques in one single answer. Also, I am not implying he should use incompatibile CSS stylesheets, I am just telling him to be aware that IE8 won't support REM. Complex calculations of border and padding doesn't make sense unless you want to support IE below version 8.

Comment: it's 3rd grade math to calculate for padding. Worth it to support all browsers in my opinion. But, point taken.