# Does the number of CSS background repetitions affect webpage efficiency?

Tags: performance, css, background-image, transparency

I'll sometimes use small, uniform pixel patterns as background images.

I've found myself using 4 x 4 or 10 x 10 pixel images in these situations, and I'm wondering if it might be better to use 50 x 50 or 100 x 100 pixel sizes instead.

Regardless, the file size will be very small, but it occurred to me that it might be much more efficient for browsers to map 30 (or so) 50x50 pixel images to a background than to map 60,000 4x4 pixel images.

*It seems like it might take up significant CPU (and therefore, battery life) for the browser to repeat a background image 60,000 + times.*

---

- Does the number of CSS background repetitions affect webpage efficiency?

---

4 x 4 px = `[1280 x 720 screen : 57,000 repeats] [3.47kb]`

100 x 100 px = `[1280 x 720 screen : 9,200 repeats] [13.83kb]`

Comment: Tal points out that RGBA should be used for solid colors. Good point, but I'll modify this question to include small pixel patterns, since the answer would still be good to know for those situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in browsers performance for background-repeat CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410994/images-in-browsers-performance-for-background-repeat-css)

Comment: @abhitalks That question is similar but it strictly asks about loading time. The chosen answer explains the speed and method in which the final image is generated, but does not explain how this affects performance outside of speed. I'm mostly asking about performance/efficiency.

Comment: "performance outside of speed" doesn't matter, really. A person's battery isn't going to die because they loaded one background as opposed to a slightly larger one

Comment: @ZachSaucier when optimizing for mobile, performance in regards to battery usage is relevant in my opinion.

Comment: @jt0dd I'm saying that the effective difference on battery life in between the two images loading is so minuscule that it *does not matter* at all. It'd be impossible to calculate and vary depending on the device

Comment: "Happy medium" is opinionated and does not have a finite solution. That alone is enough to close this question

Comment: @ZachSaucier oh you're right, I'll remove that. About the performance/battery life differences: I didn't know whether or not the differences mattered without asking. It seemed, at the time, with such high numbers of repetitions, that it might matter.

Comment: @ZachSaucier after my modification to the question, it may be a duplicate, but hopefully not of poor quality or unanswerable.

Comment: @jt0dd I'd like if you could accept my answer since no one answered a better question.

Comment: @TalGleichger You made a great point, but your answer doesn't at all address the question as it stands. Your answer is obsolete to the question, however, the simple answer to the questions is: `"No, it doesn't affect efficiency in a measurable way, and therefore there is no need to worry about it."`

Comment: If you were to make your answer along those lines, simply, I'll accept it, since that seems to be right. @TalGleichger

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say you can't use transparent background in css?

Try using RGBA - where 'a' is alpha.

i.e

```
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

Examples:
http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Comment: I don't know actually. I learned the technique from a tutorial and went with that. Didn't think of RGBA.

Comment: @jt0dd: Must have been a very old tutorial.

Comment: I'll modify this question to include small pixel patterns, since the answer would still be good to know for those situations.

Comment: Even CSS3.info is way outdated - the information on that page dates back to 2008. Every browser has supported `rgba()` for a few years now.